# Debug ActiveX in JScript using Iexplorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com, activex

I'm developing ActiveX that will be used in IExplorer JScript code I Have tst.html with script that runs ActiveX fine. Now I need to debug ActiveX code. This is how my configuration looks:

[image]

When I do run Iexplorer starts and runs my page, but brakpoints are not working.

How to debug ActiveX code with Iexplorer?

UPD

This is how iexplorer looks in process explorer

[image]

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see if IE is starting worker child processes [that run your code and are not being debugged]. If this is the case you need to either change IE settings to stop the trick, or additionally attach debugger to the processes in question. You also need to make sure you are using Native debugger, not just Script debugger (Debugger Type on your screenshot).

Comment: have updated question body with proc. explorer info. If try to attach to process when in debug mode my attach button is disabled. In case I run iexplorer with my page separately and later attach to this process - my breakpoints are disabled anyway.